# Android application using lowest density drawable

Tags: android, drawable, pixel-density

I created res drawable directories for different densities, but application always use lowest density. I created drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi and drawable-xxhdpi but in my phone with xxhdpi app using mdpi, if i delete mdpi then app using hdpi etc.

Answer (score 1):

in which device you testing your application?

if your device is suitable for hppi than it will automatically fetch images from them and it is suitable for mdpi than it will automatically fetch images from respective folder.

- A set of six generalized densities: ldpi (low) ~120dpi mdpi (medium)
  ~160dpi hdpi (high) ~240dpi xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi xxhdpi
  (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi

Comment: on many devices, previous projects working correctly on this devices with same directories

Comment: can you please provide device name?

Comment: nexus 5, lenovo vibe z

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you did put correct graphics (scaled to correct size) in your drawable folders? e.g. launcher icon should be 48 × 48 in mdpi, 72 × 72 in hdpi...etc.

Comment: i didnt change launch icons, now for check, i pasted images from another project where they showing correctly, here i see the same problem